# How can I get the actual Javascript array comparator for arrays

Tags: javascript

The JS array comparator has the functionality akin to:

`const defaultComparator = (a, b) => a === b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)`

Is there any way I can get this comparator function without writing what I think is the function? Is it available through some native prototype?

Comment: What, JS array comparator?  If you mean the default for sort, it's not that..

Comment: @Keith obviously it is not that, thus "can [I] get this comparator function without writing _what I think is the function_". And yes, I mean the default for sort.

Comment: Are you wanting the default for sort?..

Comment: @Keith see above comment.

Comment: It's possibly.. `String.prototype.localeCompare`

Comment: @Keith that is the comparator for strings only, so that does not answer my question. If you read the documentation you'll see this: "The `localeCompare()` method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.".

Comment: Indeed, and that's what sort uses..  eg.  `let defaultCompare = (a,b) => String(a).localeCompare(String(b))` would give you the same result as the default sort.

Comment: @Keith that is wrong. This negates your logic: `defaultCompare(-2, -22)`.

Comment: `[-2, -22].sort()` = `[-2, -22]`   `[-2,-22].sort(defaultCompare)` = `[-2, -22]` ,.  Seems to work, what part is wrong?

Comment: Sorry @Keith you are 100% correct. I was confused why -2 is less than -22 in Javascript land. But it makes sense now that I see that JS uses `a` and `b`'s Unicode code instead of the actual integer to sort.

Comment: Don't worry, it's an easy mistake.  It comes up a fair few time's on SO..  Logic would make you think that `[0,1,2].sort()` would be an integer sort.  But as you have found out it's a string sort as default.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.localeCompare`

This seems to be used for `Array.sort`, however, keep in mind that this sorts by Unicode code, which means `[-2, -22, 3, 4, 5]` is indeed a sorted array (despite -22 < -2).

Comment: You don't need to delete post, it was a good question.  It's usually a good idea to keep them here for future readers to see.  btw. I never down-voted you either, just in case you thought I did..

Comment: No worries, I actually never deleted it. It should be on still, right?

Comment: Oh!, that's weird.. It went red for me, and said it was deleted? ok, now though.  strange. SO having a bad day,.. Anyway, I'll up-vote your question, as I thought it was a good question..